# Wrong figure numbers (incrementing by 2): possible amsart and subcaption clash?

Tags: floats, numbering, subcaption, amsart

When using *subcaption* in an *amsart* document my figure numbers increase by 2 (instead of by 1). The problem vanishes when I switch to *article* instead of *amsart*, leading me to wonder whether this is caused by a package clash? If so, is there a quick fix, perhaps (I would like to continue using *amsart* and I would like to have subfigures in the document as well)?

MWE illustrating the issue and the compilation results follow below.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Pawel

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{\textbf{First Figure}}
\label{F1}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F1A}
        \caption{Data}\label{F1:A}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F1B}
\caption{Simulation}\label{F1:B}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{\textbf{Second Figure}}
\label{F2}%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F2A}
        \caption{Data}\label{F2:A}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F2B}
\caption{Simulation}\label{F2:B}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

Comment: I can replicate this issue on MacTeX2020 with all updates applied.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Mico. I'm on Miktex 2.9.74 on a PC and I also applied all the updates as well prior to posting, just to be on the safe side ;-)

Comment: I've opened a [new issue](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/80) on the gitlab page of the maintainer of `subcaption` and `caption` packages. Let's see what he determines.

Comment: Axel Sommerfeldt, the maintainer of the subcaption package has now provided a solution / quick fix along with a great discusion of the underlying issue. I'll post the quick fix along with a link to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mico for posting this issue on the subcaption package page on Gitlab.

A quick fix, proposed by Axel Sommerfeldt, the maintainer of the subcaption package, is to add:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{position=t}
```

This suggestion has solved the problem for me.

A great discussion of the underlying issue can be found on the [gitlab page of the subcaption package](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/80).
It would be great if Axel and/or Mico posted here as, quite obviously, I deserve no credit for the answer.

In any case, many thanks to both for their help!

Just for completeness, here's an MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[demo]{amsart} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
% Per Axel Sommerfeldt's recommendation:
\captionsetup[figure]{position=t} 

\captionsetup[figure]{textfont=bf}% optional
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{First Figure} \label{F1}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F1A}
    \caption{Data} \label{F1:A}
\end{subfigure}\quad 
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F1B}
    \caption{Simulation} \label{F1:B}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Second Figure}
\label{F2}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F2A}
    \caption{Data} \label{F2:A}
\end{subfigure}\quad 
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.25\textheight]{F2B}
    \caption{Simulation} \label{F2:B}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```